# Argument type for std::move as a parameter

Tags: c++

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18300974/462608

> If you pass an rvalue reference to another function, you are passing a
> named object, so, the object isn't received like a temporal object.

```
void some_function(A&& a)
{
   other_function(a);
}
```

> The object a would be copied to the actual parameter of
> other_function. If you want the object a continues being treated as a
> temporary object, you should use the std::move function:

```
other_function(std::move(a));
```

What would be the type of argument of `other_function`?

It can't be `other_function( A&& xyz )` because if that had been the case then `std::move` wouldn't be required?

Comment: If it's `other_function( A&& xyz )`, then `std::move` is required to convert `a` to rvalue; which could be passed to `other_function` taking rvalue-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An rvalue reference is *not an rvalue*. It's confusing because an rvalue was passed in the argument list of `some_function`; but `a`, as with other named values, is an lvalue. `std::move` is required to take `a` (an rvalue reference, which is an lvalue) and convert it into an rvalue.

It's probably easiest if you take function calls out of the example.

```
int main() {
    int&& a = 3; // compiles: binding to an rvalue
    int&& b = a; // doesn't compile: a is not an rvalue
}
```

You can't initialize an rvalue reference from a named rvalue reference, because it doesn't have the right value category.

Comment: Thank you for the proper explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can test it with this simple code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{};

void other_function(A&) {
    std::cout << "L-value\n";
}

void other_function(A&&) {
    std::cout << "R-value\n";
}

void some_function(A&& a)
{
   other_function(a); // a is an L-value
}

int main() {
    A a;
    some_function(std::move(a));
    other_function(std::move(a));
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
L-value
R-value
```

This is a test for perfect forwarding:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{};

void other_function(A&) {
    std::cout << "L-value\n";
}

void other_function(A&&) {
    std::cout << "R-value\n";
}

template<typename T>
void some_function(T&& a)
{
   other_function(std::forward<T>(a));
}

int main() {
    A a;
    some_function(a);
    some_function(std::move(a));
    return 0;

}
```

Output

```
L-value
R-value
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed examples.